# How do I fix this bug with how my data is being rendered in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, rendering

I am trying to push data into state, but it's not pushing the way I want it to. Whenever it pushes the data, when the data gets rendered, it shows the same distance multiple times rather than one time. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. I attached my code at the bottom.

```
  const d = new Date();
  const shopArray = [];
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState(false);

  const weekday = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
  ];
  const currentDay = weekday[new Date().getDay()];
  var distanceArray = [];

  const rawTime = d.toString().slice(16, 21);
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = () => {
      var i = 0;
      const shopOpening = [];
      const shopClosing = [];
      db.collection("shops")
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // Get Shop Availability
            const hourObj = doc.data().hoursOfOps;
            const timings = hourObj[currentDay];

            shopOpening.push(timings[0]);
            shopClosing.push(timings[1]);

            let [hours, minutes] = rawTime.split(":");

            const [opening, openingModifier] = timings[0].split(" ");
            let [openingHours, openingMinutes] = opening.split(":");
            if (openingHours === "12" && modifier == "AM") {
              openingHours = "00";
            }

            if (openingModifier === "PM" && openingHours !== 12) {
              openingHours = parseInt(openingHours, 10) + 12;
            }

            // Closing Time in Military Time
            const [closing, closingModifier] = timings[1].split(" ");
            let [closingHours, closingMinutes] = closing.split(":");
            if (closingHours === "12") {
              closingHours = "00";
            }

            if (closingModifier === "PM") {
              closingHours = parseInt(closingHours, 10) + 12;
            }

            const userHour = parseInt(hours);
            const openingHour = parseInt(openingHours);
            const closingHour = parseInt(closingHours);

            const shopAvailability = [];
            if (userHour >= openingHour && userHour <= closingHour) {
              if (
                userHour === closingHour &&
                closingMinutes !== "0" &&
                minutes < closingMinutes
              ) {
                shopAvailability.push("Open");
              } else if (
                userHour === closingHour &&
                closingMinutes !== "0" &&
                minutes > closingMinutes
              ) {
                shopAvailability.push("Closed");
              } else if (userHour === closingHour && closingMinutes == 0) {
                shopAvailability.push("Closed");
              } else if (
                userHour === openingHour &&
                userMinutes >= openingMinutes
              ) {
                shopAvailability.push("Open");
              } else if (
                userHour === openingHour &&
                userMinutes < openingMinutes
              ) {
                shopAvailability.push("Closed");
              } else {
                shopAvailability.push("Open");
              }
            } else if (userHour <= openingHour || userHour >= closingHour) {
              shopAvailability.push("Closed");
            } else {
              shopAvailability.push("Closed");
            }

            // Get Distance from User
            fetch(
              `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=${userLocation}&destinations=${
                doc.data().address
              }&key=${GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}`
            )
              .then((res) => res.json())
              .then((data) => {
                var number = data.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text.split(" ");
                setNumber(number[0]);
              });

            // Push data into an array for iterative rendering
            if (number == null || number !== undefined) {
              shopArray.push({
                name: doc.data().name,
                id: doc.id,
                hoursOfOps: doc.data().hoursOfOps,
                image: doc.data().shop_image,
                menu: doc.data().menu,
                location: doc.data().address,
                distanceK: number + " km",
                availability: shopAvailability,
                opening: shopOpening[i],
                closing: shopClosing[i],
              });
            }
            i = i + 1;
          });
          setData(shopArray.sort((a, b) => (a.distance < b.distance ? 1 : -1)));
        });
    };

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [userLocation, GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY]);
```

Also, when I log num[0], a different number comes up for each instance, but when I render it on the screen, the same number comes up multiple times. I think the issue lies in how I'm setting the data in the state. How do I fix this? Feel free to comment on the post to ask for further clarification.

Comment: Please, provide a wider picture, it is hard to tell why and what is happening based on this code. Is that the complete piece of the code you have? `if ` processing comes just after the `fetch` request? It could be an issue due to you need to await the fetch promise result, or it could be due to setNumber does not updates closure-captured `number`, or if it is a loop - all the loop will be complete with 1 single `number` variable due to fetch is async and its callback will be executed `later`.

Comment: @SergeySosunov I edited my post and put the entire useEffect. Once you look, could you please advise on how to fix it or maybe provide a code snippet. I've been trying to fix this bug for a really long time. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Im trying to make a CodeSandbox environment and run your application but i see there is something that is missing and something to improve a bit. So, `modifier == "AM"`, modifier is undefined, im not sure if it was `openingModifier` or if it was coming as a component prop. Same about `userMinutes`. Now about your variables like `d`, `shopArray`, `weekday`, `currentDay`, `distanceArray`, `rawTime`, please, consider shitching them to useMemo, because they are reevaluating and recreating on each render, array is also recreated, that will lead to some bugs and performance problems later.

Comment: Now about the unsubscribe method - it does nothing in your case, not all the FB functions return unsubscribe and your `.get()` only load data onse, so you need to remove that logic (clean up and remove nestings) or rewrite it to `onSnapshot` https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen .

Comment: And about the actual code you have - `setNumber(number[0]);` will not help you inside async function, it will just update randomly because of your async function can execute in different order, one request was fired first but second one gets the result faster due to network lag or any other reason, it is a no go, also, `setNumber(number[0]);` will not set the value of `number` immediately, `number` will still be equal to closure-captured value.

Comment: And about your `if` statement - im not sure which `number` you refer here, the one from state or you were trying to get this from scope-declared value in `.then` block just before it, in both way that will not work, you need to move that if inside the latest `.then` block to be able to use data that came in that then block. `setData` thing should also happen there, because of async things... Please, read about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises

Comment: @SergeySosunov have you tried to create a CodeSandbox env where you wrote this code and it works? If so, could you put the link in the comments or as an answer.

Comment: Also, how are the variables getting recreated and rerendered when they're not even in the useEffect. They only run once and are not rerendered right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246495/discussion-between-crooper-and-sergey-sosunov).